# unix join command to return all columns in one file

Tags: linux, unix, join

I have two files that I am joining on one column. After the join, I just want the output to be all of the columns, in the original order, from only one of the files. For example:

```
cat file1.tsv 
1       a       ant
2       b       bat
3       c       cat
8       d       dog
9       e       eel

cat file2.tsv 
1       I
2       II
3       III
4       IV
5       V

join -1 1 -2 1 file1.tsv file2.tsv -t $'\t' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3
1       a       ant
2       b       bat
3       c       cat
```

I know I an use `-o 1.1,1.2..` notation but my file has over two dozen columns. Is there some wildcard that I can use to say `-o 1.*` or something?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: What's the desired result? What the last section shows looks exactly like the first file?

Comment: Essentially, I would like to use `join` instead of `grep -f` because I know which column my query term will be in and `grep` takes relatively longer to run.

Comment: @tink I updated my question to add a couple of more lines to `file1.tsv`. What I want to know is if there is a way to run the `join` command as I have, but without the `-o 1.1,1.2,1.3` to get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of wildcards in the format string.

From your desired output I think that what you want may be achievable like so without having to specify all the enumerations:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' file2.tsv ) file1.tsv
1       a       ant
2       b       bat
3       c       cat
```

Or as an awk-only solution:

```
awk '{if(NR==FNR){a[$1]++}else{if($1 in a){print}}}' file2.tsv file1.tsv
1       a       ant
2       b       bat
3       c       cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we only want result from file 1, we can first extract the join field of file 2 into a separate file, then join file 1 against it:

```bash
cut -f1 file2.tsv > file2.key.tsv
join -j1 -t$'\t' file1.tsv file2.key.tsv
```

Or one-liners without the intermediate file

```bash
# using pipe
cut -f1 file2.tsv | join -j1 -t$'\t' file1.tsv -

# using process substitution supported by the shell
join -j1 -t$'\t' file1.tsv <(cut -f1 file2.tsv)
```